# If $N(x) = x-[f^{\prime}(x)]^{-1}f(x)$ and $f(x^\ast)=0$, how can I prove that $N^\prime(x^\ast) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion, newton-raphson

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\in C^{2}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let $N(x) = x-[f^{\prime}(x)]^{-1}f(x)$, supose that:

- there exist $x^\ast\in \Omega$ such that $f(x^\ast)=0$,
- for all $x\in\Omega$, we have  $N(x)\in\Omega$.
- $f^\prime(x^\ast)$ is not singular,

> How can I prove that $N^\prime(x^\ast) = 0$?

**My attempt.** We have $N(x^\ast)=x^\ast$ if, only if, $f(x^\ast)=0$. My strategy is to make Taylor's development of 
$$
N(x^\ast+v)=N(x^\ast)+N^\prime(x^\ast)v+O(v^2)
$$
and show that the term $N^\prime(x^\ast)=0$ equals zero. Note that 
\begin{align}
N(x^\ast+v)
=&
(x^\ast+v)-[f^\prime(x^\ast+v)]^{-1}f(x^\ast+v)
\\
=&
N(x^\ast)+v-[f^\prime(x^\ast+v)]^{-1}f(x^\ast+v)
\\
=&
N(x^\ast)+v-[f^\prime(x^\ast)]^{-1}f(x^\ast+v)
\\
&\qquad+
\Big([f^\prime(x^\ast)]^{-1}-[f^\prime(x^\ast+v)]^{-1}\Big)f(x^\ast+v)
\\
&=
N(x^\ast)+v-[f^\prime(x^\ast)]^{-1}\Big(f(x^\ast)+f^\prime(x^\ast)\cdot v+O(v^2)\Big)
\\
&\qquad+
\Big([f^\prime(x^\ast)]^{-1}-[f^\prime(x^\ast+v)]^{-1}\Big)\Big(f(x^\ast)+f^\prime(x^\ast)\cdot v+O(v^2)\Big)
\\
&=
N(x^\ast)+v-[f^\prime(x^\ast)]^{-1}\Big(f^\prime(x^\ast)\cdot v+O(v^2)\Big)
\\
&\qquad+
\Big([f^\prime(x^\ast)]^{-1}-[f^\prime(x^\ast+v)]^{-1}\Big)\Big(f^\prime(x^\ast)\cdot v+O(v^2)\Big)
\\
&=
N(x^\ast)+O(v^2)
\\
&\qquad+
\Big([f^\prime(x^\ast)]^{-1}-[f^\prime(x^\ast+v)]^{-1}\Big)\Big(f^\prime(x^\ast)\cdot v+O(v^2)\Big)
\end{align}
But I can not eliminate the term $ v $ from the above expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply evaluating $N'(x)$ from its definition?

Assuming there exists $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ in a neighborhood around $x^*$, as your problem satisfies the conditions of the [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Then let $J[N](x)$ denote the Jacobian matrix of $N$ (which is preferable as notation when not working on a single dimension).

Rewriting:
$$
N(x) = x - (J[f](x))^{-1}f(x)
$$

By inverse function theorem:

$$
N(x) = x - J[g](x)f(x)
$$

Now, taking the Jacobian of the above expression:

$$
N(x) = x - J[g](x)f(x)
$$

Deriving:
$$
J[N](x) = J[x](x) -\left(J\left[J[g](x)\right](x)\right)f(x)-J[g](x)J[f](x)
$$
The first term is trivial:
$$
J[N](x) = I -\left(J\left[J[g](x)\right](x)\right)f(x)-J[g](x)J[f](x)
$$
The last term is the identity due to the aforementioned theorem:
$$
J[N](x) = I -\left(J\left[J[g](x)\right](x)\right)f(x)-I
$$
$$
J[N](x) = -\left(J\left[J[g](x)\right](x)\right)f(x)
$$

Now, it might be difficult to compute $J\left[J[g](x)\right](x)$, and it is also  a 3 dimensional tensor, and this notation may be crappy. But we have that $f(x^*)=0$, hence that term does not matter. So evaluating at $x^*$, we get a null matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Since
\begin{eqnarray*}
N(x^*)v&=&\lim_{t\to0}\frac{N(x^*+tv)-N(x^*)}{t} \\
&=&\lim_{t\to0}\bigg\{ v-\frac{[f^{\prime}(x^*+tv)]^{-1}f(x^*+tv)-[f^{\prime}(x^*)]^{-1}f(x^*)}{t}\bigg\}\\
&=&v-\lim_{t\to0}\frac{[f^{\prime}(x^*+tv)]^{-1}[f(x^*+tv)-f(x^*)]}{t}-\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\{[f^{\prime}(x^*+tv)]^{-1}-[f^{\prime}(x^*)]^{-1}\}f(x^*)}{t}\\
&=&v-v=0,
\end{eqnarray*}
one has $N(x^*)v=0$ and hence $N(x^*)=0$.